# Why does the code below not work? (using pyautogui to create a bot in a game)

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
x=0
while x==0:
    target = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Desktop\ bot\references\target.png'),region=(0,0,1024,768),confidence=.7)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    target2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Desktop\ bot\references\target2.png'),region=(0,0,1024,768),confidence=.7)
    print(target,target2)
    if target and target2 is None:
        pyautogui.keyDown('W')
    elif target or target2 != None:
        pyautogui.keyUp("W")
        print(target or target2)
        target_point = pyautogui.center(target or target2)
        targetx, targety = target_point
        pyautogui.click(targetx, targety)
        x=1
```

(the code should be recreated with the modules imported)Hey everyone! I was trying to create a simple bot for a game that moves forward when it doesnt detect a target, but stops moving when the target is detected. Why does this not get the W key to be pressed down? Whats weird is that when target or target2.png is detected, it presses W otherwise it doesnt?

Comment: Try `if target is None and target2 is None:`

Comment: Yes! It worked thank you!! @Mike67 should the bottom part also be `elif target !=None or target2 !=None:` or not?

Comment: yes - make that change also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that python treats some values as True, and others as False.

In Python, `None`, `0`, and `""` (empty string) are all considered False. Any other value is considered True.

In your code, there is this line:

```
if target and target2 is None:
```

While the phrase sounds right (if both are None), what's really happening is `target` is converted to a boolean in the evaluation:

```
if bool(target) == True and target2 is None:
```

Since `target` is not `None/0/""`, the bool conversion returns True. This is causing the unexpected behavior in the code.

The same idea applies to the `elif` statement